# What to do when it seems that downvotes are not justified (for example, when they are directed "against" the person and not "against" the question)?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289549/unusual-equation-obtained-while-trying-to-resolve-an-open-problem) now has a score of $-2$ and it could  be that it will be lowered still.

It is an elementary attempt to resolve an open problem.

I shared it with you because I am an amateur and almost all of mathematics that I learn is somewhere from the web and I had some faith in you.

Also, the question is not an uninteresting one at all.

You can politely tell me not to participate on the site.

The question is:

> What to do when it seems that downvotes are not justified (for example, when they are directed "against" the person and not "against" the question)?

Comment: I see that you have asked 18 questions yet have given 0 answers on MO main. It would do you well to answer a few (non-soft) questions instead of simply asking them. MO is a site about giving and taking. A good asker is one who just as often answers non-soft questions as he asks them.

Answer (score 11):

When it seems downvotes are not justified, the first thing to do is to reconsider. Read what people write about the question, see for yourself whether the question is the kind that generally flies here or is lacking in some way, etc.

If after reconsidering it still seems downvotes are unjustified, you have two courses of action. One is, get over it. Don't worry about it, do something else. The second course of action is to contact the moderators and make your case to them. They, and they alone, can do something if there really is unjustified downvoting going on. You are wasting your time posting here on meta, as there's not a thing anyone reading your complaint here can do (anyone other than a moderator, that is).